# Setting default position for new toolwindow in VsPackage

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, vspackage, visual-studio-sdk

I'm creating a VsPackage with a ToolWindow and having an issue setting the default position of the window when it is opened for the first time. I need it docked as a new tab in the 'main window' (not exactly sure what this is called - it is the center area of the IDE where the Code Editor window opens by default.), but instead, it is opening as a floating window on in the top-left.

I understand I can move the window to the right position and it will be saved for the next time in my settings, but I would like it defaulted to this position so the users don't have to do this.

```
[ProvideToolWindow(typeof(MyToolWindow),
        Style = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsDockStyle.Linked,
        Window = "GUID Here")]
```

I know I have to set a specific guid, but I can't seem to find the right one - this list doesn't seem to list what I need: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.toolwindowguids_fields(v=vs.140).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Style = VsDockStyle.MDI`.

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: This worked! I kind of thought the 'main area' wasn't technically a window, but something else.  New code: `    [ProvideToolWindow(typeof(MyToolWindow),
        Style = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsDockStyle.MDI)]`